# Virtualhosts names not working on apache on Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, osx-yosemite

I'm dropping MAMP in favor of native Yosemite apache. I have troubles defining and accessing my vhosts, they seems to be unreachable.

I've followed this gist: https://gist.github.com/GabrielCousin/7522e032ad69879463df

And when do a `sudo apachectl -S` I have my vhosts:

```
[ guillaume MBPro ~ ] sudo apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:1)
                 alias guillaume.dev
         port 80 namevhost api.wisembly.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:13)
                 alias static.host.dev
                 alias api.host.biz
         port 80 namevhost app.host.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:26)
                 alias app.host.biz

ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="guillaume" id=501
Group: name="staff" id=20
```

I've declared these hosts in `/etc/hosts`. I reach `http://localhost` perfectly, it lists my files and folders in my default directory. But when calling the alias `guillaume.dev`, it waits, waits and waits before going into timeout.

When I do a `ping guillaume.dev`, it is unreachable:

```
PING guillaume.dev (172.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

This is the same problem for every other host I define, it seems that ServerName and ServerAlias does not work (since guillaume.dev, alias of localhost does not work *but* localhost if perfectly defined in the vhosts file and reachable).

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does your `ifconfig lo` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your hosts file. I think you meant `127.0.0.1` not `172.0.0.1`.

Or you can add `172.0.0.1` with:

```
ifconfig lo0 alias 172.0.0.1
```

Comment: Gosh... How could I've missed that O_o Seems after hours my eyes where full of sh*t, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Hey, it happens to all of us ...all the time. Glad to help!